# Using objdump for ARM architecture: Disassembling to ARM

Tags: linux, arm, disassembly, objdump

I have an object file and am trying to disassemble it. When I use:

```
objdump -d example.o
```

I get an assembly in code in the file format of `elf64-x86-64`.

I am trying to disassemble this into ARM, how do I go about doing this?

Comment: Just to clarify, are you saying you have a x86_64 executable/object file and would like it disassembled as ARM instructions?

Comment: yes, a professor has me working on a project and what i want to do is disassemble the object file but i guess it is a x86 executable. If i use arm-linux-objdump i should be able to disassemble into ARM right?

Comment: For compiling as well as for disassembly, you need to use ARM cross compiler toolchain.

Answer (score 20):

If you want to do disassemble of ARM code, you'd better have an ARM tool chain, this is what I got:

http://bb.osmocom.org/trac/wiki/toolchain

After you have this, you can use arm-elf-objdump instead of objdump.
The command I used is

```
arm-elf-objdump -D -b binary -marm binaryfile.dat
```

If you look the manpage, you will find "-b" is followed by the file type. Sorry I don't know how to tell -b you want to analyze a .o file. "-marm" will tell the cpu is ARM.

Hope this can help you.

Comment: Now you can just install it with `sudo apt install gcc-arm-none-eabi`, and disassemble arm binaries with `gcc-arm-none-eabi-objdump -d -marm <binary>`.

Comment: In my case (Ubuntu 18.04), `gcc-arm-none-eabi-objdump` didn't work,
but `arm-none-eabi-objdump` worked.

Answer (score 8):

Before disassembling the binary, check the filetype via "file", for example:

> file dnslookup.o
>
> dnslookup.o: ELF 32-bit LSB  relocatable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV),
> not stripped

So now we know it is an ARM object or ELF file.

To disassemble arm object file use
`arm-linux-gnueabi-objdump`.   In Ubuntu, "arm-linux-gnueabi-objdump" is the default disassembler for ARM binaries - no compilation is needed.

To install it, just do:

sudo apt-get install binutils-arm-linux-gnueabi

There are also other binaries inside this package that can further analyze the ARM binaries for you.

Answer (score 7):

Compile `binutils` with the right target(s) to get binutils objdump binary that knows how to disassemble ARM.

http://www.gnu.org/software/binutils/

`./configure --enable-targets=all` for example.

Pick your targets, make and use the new `objdump` binary that is your-target-aware. See the `binutils/README` file for more information on targeting.

```
objdump -D t3c # stock binary
objdump: t3c: File format not recognized
```

vs.

```
./../../binutils-2.22/binutils/objdump -D t3c # latest compiled from source with all targets
In archive t3c:

t3c:arm:     file format mach-o-le


Disassembly of section .text:

00002d94 <start>:
    2d94:   e59d0000    ldr r0, [sp]
...
```

Answer (score 4):

Install the [ELDK](http://www.denx.de/wiki/view/DULG/ELDKAvailability) and use arm-linux-objdump. You're trying to disassemble ARM instructions using a program that only knows x86.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue on macOS (arm64). For some reason, configure had located `objdump` from the Xcode SDK, and I'm not cross-compiling, so Xcode must contain the Intel binaries as well.

All I had to do was `brew install binutils` – problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Debian 12. So I install `arm-trusted-firmware-tools` which is Debian's `arm` disassembly tool:

```
sudo apt install arm-trusted-firmware-tools
```

After that I use similar command as above (qiuhan1989), and save the file as .asm one

```
arm-none-eabi-objdump -D -b binary -marm binary.elf > binary.elf.asm
```