# Objdump ARM aarch64 code?

Tags: arm, objdump, arm64

I have an elf arm aarch64 binary and i want to disassemble it .text section using objdump.My machine is amd64.

I tried [Using objdump for ARM architecture: Disassembling to ARM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3859453/help-using-objdump-disassembling-to-arm) but objdump is not identifying the binary so not able to disassemble it.

Comment: If you have Ubuntu or Debian, an alternative is to install *binutils-multiarch*, which can disassembler many different CPU types.  Most likely other systems may have a similarly configured package.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Go to http://releases.linaro.org/latest/components/toolchain/binaries/ and get your choice of `gcc-linaro-aarch64-linux-gnu-4.9-*` like for example `gcc-linaro-aarch64-linux-gnu-4.9-2014.07_linux.tar.bz2`.

After unpacking invoke `aarch64-linux-gnu-objdump`, ie:

```
echo "int main(void) {return 42;}" > test.c
gcc-linaro-aarch64-linux-gnu-4.9-2014.07_linux/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc -c test.c
gcc-linaro-aarch64-linux-gnu-4.9-2014.07_linux/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-objdump -d test.o
```

to get objdump.

```
test.o:     file format elf64-littleaarch64


Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000000000 <main>:
   0:   52800540    mov w0, #0x2a                   // #42
   4:   d65f03c0    ret
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the same toolchain which you used to compile the binary

In case of **ARM architecture**, it would generally be like **arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc**, so for **objdump** you should use

> **arm-linux-gnueabi-objdump**
>
> **At present I guess you must using x86 toolchain(objdump) to disassemble the binary compiled using ARM toolchain hence the error**